# Android permission как поддерживать старые версии?

Tags: android

В новых андроидах нужно получать права в рантайме. Как при этом поддерживать старые андроиды, например 4??

Comment: Как и раньше -- для них достаточно записи в манифесте.

Comment: Я так понял, если цель 23, то записи в манифесте игнорятся?, если <23 то разрешения запрашиваются как раньше? Даже если андроид 15? Если такой будет, может и не будет. Посмотрим через 7 лет. Нужно вернуться к этому посту. Если stackoverflow еще будет, или кеш гугла или другой кеш

Answer (score 1):

Если цель (`targetSdkVersion`) - 23, то на 23 девайсе будут применяться правила запроса разрешений в рантайме и игнориться манифест. Если запустить на 21 девайсе, то запроса не будет, но запись в манифесте нужна.

Если цель <23 и запустить на девайсе с 23, то в рантайме апроса не будет и разрешения будут браться из манифеста так же, как и на девайсах с <23

Comment: У меня старое приложение есть. где target 16. В нем есть 2 разрешения,`WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` и `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. При использовании на девайсе с андроид 7, при записи данных на карту - ошибка permission denied. Но при чтении, такой ошибки нету!

Comment: @Devel0, это странно. Возможно, гугл где-то что-то поменял и таки надо запросить разрешение

Comment: Хорошо, а как запрашивать, если в sdk 16 нету метода checkSelfPermission?

Comment: @Devel0, Возможно таки стоит поднять версии либ? Несовместимость кода старых версий с новыми ОС вполне ожидаемая вещь...

Comment: Поднимать версию? Как это повлияет на гугл плей?

Comment: @Devel0, не понял вопроса.